# Tabule substrings in file names

Tags: bash, awk

I have a large directory of files.  Many of the filenames have similar substrings in between underscores.  I want a tabulation of how many files there are with each substring.  Say for example I had the following files:

```
> ls
sfjjs_cat_aawlhi
asfdj_dog_ahgahlkeg
afs_dog_akhg
fasah_cat_chaghe
fhs_dog_hghg
fof_turtle_hahgg
```

How would I get an output like?

```
1 turtle
2 cat
3 dog
```

Is such a thing possible?  If it matters, I'm using ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *_* | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort | uniq -c
      2 cat
      3 dog
      1 turtle
```

The above assumes you don't have any newlines and you have max 2 `_`s in your file names as in your provided sample input. Add another `| sort -n` if you want the output ordered by counts of occurrences:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *_* | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 turtle
      2 cat
      3 dog
```

and you can remove the leading blanks with `sed` if you care:

```
$ printf '%s\n' *_* | cut -d'_' -f2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/^ *//'
1 turtle
2 cat
3 dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Done with awk command

```
 ls |awk -F "_" 'NF==3 && /_/{a[$2]++}END{for(x in a){print a[x],x}}'
```

output

```
1 turtle
2 cat
3 dog
```

Comment: `/_/` seems redundant if you've already verified 3 `_`-separated fields